# Nodejs: Reading in a large file as a string and looking for certain strings within using a mask

Tags: node.js, fs

I would like to be able to read in a large file (greater than 1GB) as a string into node.js (I don't really care about efficiency), once done, I want to be able search through the file using a mask for example **FILE_XXX_XXXX_XXXXXXXX**, 
 
X being any character and store the results in an array. Currently my method is to simply read in the file using 
 
**fs.readFileSync(srcPath, 'utf8');** 
 
this however results in the error
 
**Error: Cannot create a string longer than 0x3fffffe7 characters** 
 
I've looked around and am aware of "piping" but am unsure as to how to implement this(or if it's even suitable for what I want to do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is [fs.createReadStream](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options):

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const readStream = fs.createReadStream('myfile.txt');

readStream
  .on('data', function(chunk) {
    // check if chunk.toString() contains what you're looking for here
  })
  .on('end', function () {
    console.log('done');
  });
```

You can use a regexp to match your mask, see https://regexr.com/